# Sendkeys "variable"

Tags: vbscript

Is it possible to use the `SendKeys` the type the characters inside a variable.
for example I got characters stored in variable `firstname = Regie`

Here is my code.

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim objSysInfo, objUser
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")

Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objSysInfo.UserName)
firstname = objUser.givenName 
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.AppActivate "Notepad"
WScript.Sleep 400
WshShell.SendKeys "{& objUser.givenName}"
WScript.Sleep 250
```

Or is there any way to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, try this little script on the command line, it will print "test".

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
keys = "test"
WshShell.SendKeys keys
```